# Flutter 1.17 Navigation Rail with Named Routes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

With the release of version 1.17 of Flutter I want to take advantage of the new [NavigationRail](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRail-class.html) widget

As a novice I currently built my web app around the tutorial [here](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/template-layouts-and-navigation-in-flutter-web/), using [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) and Named Routes.

How would I apply the same architecture found in the tutorials to example found in the NavigationRail documentation?

```
int _selectedIndex = 0;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Row(
       children: <Widget>[
         NavigationRail(
           selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
           onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
             setState(() {
               _selectedIndex = index;
             });
           },
           labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
           destinations: [
             NavigationRailDestination(
               icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
               selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
               label: Text('First'),
             ),
             NavigationRailDestination(
               icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border),
               selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book),
               label: Text('Second'),
             ),
             NavigationRailDestination(
               icon: Icon(Icons.star_border),
               selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.star),
               label: Text('Third'),
             ),
           ],
         ),
         VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
         // This is the main content.
         Expanded(
           child: Center(
             child: Text('selectedIndex: $_selectedIndex'),
           ),
         )
       ],
     ),
   );
 }
```

Comment: does navigation rail have web support?

Comment: Yes it is as detailed here  [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-navigationrail-widget-new-in-v1-17-4b8c5416a081)